# unix bc command and order of operation

Tags: unix, math, bc

I'm encountering a strange issue with the basic unix "bc" command on a mac and I want to just make sure I'm understanding it correctly.  From the man pages, it says it respects order of operations, which I remember from my schooldays as "My Dear Aunt Sally" (multiply, divide, add, subtract)

When evaluating the following string in bc I'm getting an unexpected value

```
5/2+4+6-8*4+5*7+8
23
```

However, if I go through and I parenthesize the order of operations I stated earlier, I get a different result:

```
(((5/2)+(4+6))-((8*4)+((5*7)+8)))
-63
```

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the bc command, or math?

Comment: Sure your parenthesis is false, it should be (5/2)+4+6-(8*4)+(5*7)+8. Minus is for 8*4 product not up to the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that x-y+z is not equal to x-(y+z). Thus you are committing a mistake by expecting 5/2+4+6-8*4+5*7+8 to be equal to (((5/2)+(4+6))-((8*4)+((5*7)+8))). Also, you need to study a bit more about operator precedence and truncation in division. For example, 5/2 though is equal to 2.5 is truncated to 2.
Hence, 5/2+4+6-8*4+5*7+8 = 2+4+6-32+35+8 = 23.
Hope, it helped

Comment: thank you- i was taking the "my dear aunt sally" rule too literally... I think now that it's coming back to me it's "(my dear) (aunt sally)".

Comment: @infomofo.You always welcome. Exactly, * and / have the same precedence, and + and -  have the same precedence.

Comment: And within that same precedence, you go from left to right.